# Select all dates between first day of month and current date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Just want to select all dates between  cureent date and first day of month . I want to use fill all dates in a temp table

```
declare @temp table 
 (
   ddate datetime 
  )
```

I have tried with  `with cte`  and i don't want to use while loop becuase i want to avoid while in stored procedure .

For example as today is `11-oct-2012`

so temp table should have 11 rows starting from `1-oct-2012` to `11-oct-2012`

Comment: Why don't you want to use a while loop?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE=CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)  -- mm/dd/yyyy
DECLARE @endDate DATE=GETDATE() -- mm/dd/yyyy

SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(Day,Number,@startDate) 
FROM  master..spt_values 
WHERE Type='P'
AND DATEADD(day,Number,@startDate) <= @endDate
```

OR

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME=CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) -- mm/dd/yyyy
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME= GETDATE() -- mm/dd/yyyy

;WITH Calender AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @endDate
)
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,25) 
FROM Calender
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @temp table (ddate datetime);

insert @temp
select DATEDIFF(d,0,GetDate()-Number)
from master..spt_values
where type='p' and number < DatePart(d,Getdate())
order by 1;
```

Comment: your answer is very  good  , short  and i use this but @Biswas answer is before so i accepted that one as answer because that also give me correct record.

Comment: one more thing you have calculated days from 1900 ? am i rt ? so its possible that days count overflow  and its not give us correct answer ? i have just doubt ..

Comment: No I have not calculated from 1900. `Datediff(d,0` is only used to strip the time from `GetDate()-Number` which only produces dates in the current month.

Comment: Hey @RichardTheKiwi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853319/combine-today-and-running-total-results-in-one-sql-query for you and i am sure you can solve this with in seconds.....

Answer (score 0):

use current_date add days of every the generated series to the days, the series could from the first day of the month subtract current_day to 0, such today 02 Jun, the series could be (-1, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME=CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) -- mm/dd/yyyy
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME= CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '31/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) -- mm/dd/yyyy

;WITH Calender AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @endDate
)
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,25) 
FROM Calender
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```